# Mac XAMPP Drush 'needs a higher bootstrap level to run'

Tags: drush

I have installed Drush on a Mac and can use it to download modules for the drupal projects I have in XAMPP. However serveral drush commands like `drush up` give a `needs a higher bootstrap level to run` error message. How do I get around this issue?

```
Pauls-iMac:mysite Trotter$ drush up
Command pm-update needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will   [error]
need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run
this command.
The drush command 'up' could not be executed.                        [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.         [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a
configured database. In this case you can select another site with a
working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri
parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for
details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be
wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to: 
 Drupal version        :  7.38                                      
 Site URI              :  http://default                            
 Database driver       :  mysql                                     
 Database hostname     :  localhost                                 
 Database port         :                                            
 Database username     :  root                                      
 Database name         :  mysite                             
 PHP executable        :  /usr/bin/php                              
 PHP configuration     :                                            
 PHP OS                :  Darwin                                    
 Drush script          :  /Users/Trotter/.composer/vendor/drush/dru 
                      sh/drush.php                              
 Drush version         :  7.0.0                                     
 Drush temp            :  /tmp                                      
 directory                                                          
 Drush configuration   :                                            
 Drush alias files     :                                            
 Drupal root           :  /applications/xampp/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite 
 Site path             :  sites/default
```

The drupal sites work fine, just not with Drush. I have tried [forcing 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost](https://www.drupal.org/node/1428638).

I notice that my issue is very similar to [MAC -> Drush higher bootstrap level?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123346/mac-drush-higher-bootstrap-level). The answer supplied by [ChristophWeber](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/33911/christophweber) sounds promising, but does not include enough information more me to be able to try it. For example I cannot find my .bashrc file which [I gather should be in my home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662713/where-do-i-find-the-bashrc-file-on-mac), and if I needed to create it myself I'm not sure what should be in it.

Comment: .bashrc is for linux systems afaik. I think the equivalent for macs is  .bash_profile

Comment: Thanks Beebee. I have a .bash_profile. The only line in it is the one for composer (how I installed Drush) `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Try this: Open terminal and type `which php`. If it's not pointing to your XAMPP's bin directory, then in your .bash_profile file add: `PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH` then type `source ~/.bash_profile && which php` in your terminal. If it's pointing to XAMPP's bin folder then your php is now set to XAMPP's one.

Comment: Word of caution: Although Mac is case insensitive, if you want to do things correctly and avoid future problems, always respect the cases in file paths and names. For example: `/applications/xampp` should really be `/Applications/XAMPP`. Is this coming from your aliases file or did you manually change this to hide the real path of your site?

Comment: Are you calling the drush commands from the root of your local drupal install? I had similar issues with my acquia install on windows, don't know if that's the case but that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Beebee, the steps you described worked perfectly. Could you type them up as an answer so that I can mark this as answered and give you the credit? Regarding the directory names it is actually `/Applications/XAMPP` on my system. Maybe I didn't type the uppercase characters when cd'ing to the drupal site directory. If this is likely to cause problems I'll make sure I am case sensitive in the future. Cheers

Comment: Yes I had cd'ed into the root of my local Drupal directory before calling the Drush Commands.

Comment: I'm not sure what to write as an answer... so you had 2 different PHP's running on your system? In that case I'd flag this as a duplicate of the answer you linked on your question ;)